# Java-Binary Search Error

Tags: java, binary-search

This is my program for binary searching:

```
  import java.io.*;
    public class Program14
{
public void ArraySearching()throws IOException
{   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int A[]=new int[15];
    System.out.println("Input an array of 15 elements in descending order");
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        int j=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        j=A[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Input the number to be searched");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Binary search");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for linear search");
    int ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
    {
        int flag=0,low,up,mid=0;
        low=0;
        up=14;
        while(low<=up)
        {
            mid=(low+up)/2;
            if(n>A[mid])
            low=mid+1;
            else if(n<A[mid])
            up=mid-1;
            else
            {flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==1)
        System.out.println("Element at position"+(mid+1));
        else 
        System.out.println("Element not found");
        break;
    }
}}}
```

The output is always "Element not found". Could someone please point out my mistake? The linear search part of the program hasn't been done yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int A[]=new int[15];
    System.out.println("Input an array of 15 elements in descending order");
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        int j=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        A[i]=j;
    }
    System.out.println("Input the number to be searched");
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Binary search");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for linear search");
    int ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int flag=0,low,up,mid=0;
        low=0;
        up=14;
        int count = 0;
        mid=(low+up)/2;
        while(low<=up)
        {

            if(n>A[mid]){
                                mid--;
                            }
            else if(n<A[mid]){

                mid++;
                            }
            else
            {

                flag=1;
            break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        if(flag==1)
            System.out.println("Element at position"+(mid+1));
        else 
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: This solution is wrong. Modifying the mid value (mid-- or mid++) actually does not perform a binary search, it just searches from one value to the next until the answer is found.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
j=A[i];
```

should be:

```
A[i]=j;
```

Also, you need to swap the location of the following two lines:

```
low = mid + 1;
up = mid - 1;
```

Comment: i changed it but it still says "Element not Found"